# How do I specify the server's port number with github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql?

Tags: mysql, go, connection-string

I am using the following package for MySQL

http://godoc.org/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#MySQLDriver.Open

And my code is:

```
import (
  "bufio"
  "database/sql"
  _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "me_id:username@tcp(db1.abc.com)/dataname?timeout=2s")
```

But I am getting the error message of `error: dial tcp: missing port in address db1.abc.com`

Is there anyway that I can specify the server without any port number?
I am porting the oroginal code in Python and it has no port number.

Comment: Try using port 3306, default for MySql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mentioned by [ANisus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694331/anisus), the default port for MySQL is 3306.

Please try with:

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "me_id:username@tcp(db1.abc.com:3306)/dataname?timeout=2s")
```

and see if that fixes the problem. The MySQL driver doesn't seem to provide a default port if one isn't specified.